# Tikzposter block with no content

Tags: block, tikzposter

I want to use a tikzposter block as a title with no content inside the block. I am currently using:

```
\block{Proposed trajectory}{}
```

Which gives me:

[image]

However, I would like to have no white bar at all, just a blue bar with the title.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\begin{document}

{
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{blocktitlebgcolor}
\colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{white}
\block{}{\centering \bfseries \LARGE Proposed}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think samcarter's answer makes the block a bit too big (If you want the banner to have the same hight as the banner on other blocks this will become a problem)

So I suggest defining a new block style:

```
\defineblockstyle{Justtitle}{
        }{
        \ifBlockHasTitle
                \draw[color=framecolor, fill=blocktitlebgcolor,
                rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners] (blocktitle.south west)
                rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
        \fi
}
```

and then using it before a banner only block, and using `\useblockstyle{Default}` after the title only block.

An example:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\defineblockstyle{Justtitle}{
        }{
        \ifBlockHasTitle
                \draw[color=framecolor, fill=blocktitlebgcolor,
                rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners] (blocktitle.south west)
                rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
        \fi
}
\begin{document}

\block{otherblock}{}
\useblockstyle{Justtitle}
\block{bob}{}
\useblockstyle{Default}
\block{normal again}{}
\end{document}
```

Returns:

[image]

Where the height of the *bob* is the same as that of the *otherblock* and the *normal again* banner.