# Tikzposter combining title only blocks and offset on the next block

Tags: tikzposter

Some time ago now, I answered this question [Tikzposter block with no content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418765/tikzposter-block-with-no-content) And I thought all was nice and good.

But after having had to use the command I created I realized that around 2cm of blank space is inserted in after any `titleblock`. This can bee fixed with the `titleoffsety=2cm` and `bodyoffsety=2cm` on any top block right below the title block. To streamline this I could make an `aftertitleblock` that adds this, but it seems like a dirty macro if I need to make a new macro to clean after myself.

So I was wondering if there was a way to remove the 2cm of emptyness, from within the `defineblockstyle` command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\defineblockstyle{Justtitle}{
        }{
        \ifBlockHasTitle
                \draw[color=framecolor, fill=blocktitlebgcolor,
                rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners] (blocktitle.south west)
                rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
        \fi
}
\newcommand{\titleblock}[1]{\useblockstyle{Justtitle}\block{#1}{}\useblockstyle{Default}}

\begin{document}
\titleblock{Cool title}
\begin{columns}
        \column{0.5}
        \block[titleoffsety=2cm,bodyoffsety=2cm]{cool block title}{block text} %NOTE THE OFFSET
        \block{next block}{more text}
        \column{0.5}
        \block{even cooler, but wrongly placed title}{Super cool text here}%NOTE THE LACK OF OFFSET
        \block{hello}{duck}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Produces:
[image: A picture Yay]

Comment: I don't completely understand the code (`tikzposter.cls`, line 399) but I think that even when body is empty, some parbox is defined for it and space is reserved. This can be seen in [your solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418774/1952) where there's some space below `bob` box.

Comment: And discrepancies between title and body heights in [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418769/1952) solution are due to block `linewidth` which are always drawn behind|around boxes text.

Comment: @Ignasi I figured that it always defined them, but I was wondering wether or not I could define the `titleblock` command to remove them afterwards?

Comment: You can always investigate how high is an empty box and apply the corresponding shift to block below them. But I think it's easier to try to define a new kind of block or use samcarter solution with a thinner inner separation to compesate line width.

Comment: Hackish fix that works for your example at least: `\newcommand{\titleblock}[1]{\useblockstyle{Justtitle}\block[bodyinnersep=-1cm]{#1}{}\useblockstyle{Default}}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think 1cm is a bit overkill, but it works great ;-) would you make it into an answer? I ended up going for 0.4cm, but the difference might be because of my non MWE environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `tikzposter` calculates the height of the body of a block, it does

```
\setlength{\TP@blockbodyheight}{\ht\TP@blockbodybox + \dp\TP@blockbodybox +2\TP@blockbodyinnersep}
```

As you can see two times the `blockbodyinnersep` is added to the height. You can make use of that fact and set the `bodyinnersep` in your `\titleblock` macro to an appropriate *negative* length:

```
\newcommand{\titleblock}[1]{\useblockstyle{Justtitle}\block[bodyinnersep=-4mm]{#1}{}\useblockstyle{Default}}
```

Complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\defineblockstyle{Justtitle}{
        }{
        \ifBlockHasTitle
                \draw[color=framecolor, fill=blocktitlebgcolor,
                rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners] (blocktitle.south west)
                rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
        \fi
}
\newcommand{\titleblock}[1]{\useblockstyle{Justtitle}\block[bodyinnersep=-4mm]{#1}{}\useblockstyle{Default}}

\begin{document}
\titleblock{Cool title}
\begin{columns}
        \column{0.5}
        \block{cool block title}{block text} 
        \block{next block}{more text}
        \column{0.5}
        \block{even cooler, but wrongly placed title}{Super cool text here}
        \block{hello}{duck}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```